# Adding annotations to PDF files online

Tags: php, pdf, annotations

Is it possible to add annotations to existing PDF files (and display visual representations of those annotations when viewed) online using a server-side language, (preferably PHP)? Are there any libraries to do so?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's a somewhat substantial discussion about pdf libraries on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php
You might find something useful.

Comment: Link doesn't exists!

Answer (score -1):

That answer doesn't respond to the actual question. There are numerous libraries that can annotate PDF files online using PHP. FlexPaper delivers some of these libraries. You can give it a try here:

http://flexpaper.com/download/#Classic

Note: I am affiliated with this product company

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to your own site. Instead, put the essential information in your answer itself. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)